# HTML layout with vertical divider and menu between sections - how?

Tags: html, css, layout, vertical-alignment

Could someone give some hints how to achieve HTML layout [like this](http://rytky.kapsi.fi/kuvat/Selection_001.png)? I don't have understanding how to create menu section between "left" and "right".

Menu could be floating or not, it doesn't matter.

I'm using this for basic structure (this is just my current try, so it can be changed if needed):

```html
<style>
body, html{
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}    
    
#left {
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    float:left;
    width:50%
}
#right {
    background-color:#999999;
    float:right;
    width:50%
}
</style>

<html>
<body>
    <div id="left">
        <p>This should go to left.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <p>This should go to right.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would highly appreciate if it was achieved only by HTML5 and CSS.

It should be responsive, of course.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I want a pony! Welcome to Stack Overflow, What have you tried? Have you reviewed the [**What To Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance notes?

Comment: You mean it's hard without something else than HTML/CSS?

Comment: No...it's expected that you make some effort to show us what you have tried to do to solve this yourself instead of just posting a vague request.

Comment: Oh, I see. Actually I have done right and left sections - code snippet added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use this at least to have something to start:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 0;
        }
        #left {
            background-color: green;
            width: 50%;
            height: 100vh;
            float: left;
        }
        #right {
            background-color: orange;
            width: 50%;
            height: 100vh;
            float: right;
        }
        #center {
            background-color: gray;
            width: 20%;
            height: 30%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-top: -15%;
            margin-left: -10%;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
    <div id="left">TEST A</div>
    <div id="center">TEST B</div>
    <div id="right">TEST C</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks pretty much as answer for my need. Thanks! I don' fully understand how it works, but I bet googling helps.